# How to have the cell value blank instead of undefined in google app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this script which runs correctly but the problem is that where there is no value to be calculated it returns "undefined" and "#NUM!" in the cell instead of leaving the cell blank.
The script gets the price from the products sheet depending on the currency in column O and product code  which can be in either column P or column AA. If a product code exists in column P then the price it put in column Z. If there is no product code in column P then column Z for that row should be blank. Likewise if there is a product code in column AA then the price is put in column AC for that product. The problem I have is that when the product code cell is blank in column P the script puts "undefined" in the corresponding Product price cell in column Z. Also if there is no product code in column AA the script is putting "#NUM!" in the corresponding cell in column AC. If there is no product code I require the Product price cell to be left blank.
The spreadsheet can be viewed
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dk57-ulWiHD_fYbEnYcMkqwQyDKkEyQVPNetqMVIgN0/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for any help

```
function updatePrice() {  
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var jobSheet = ss.getSheetByName('BLOCK ORDERS');
  var productSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jbG_PLWU_eXfQTkwUn1krtYfzniw7HwnwnunhohzL60").getSheetByName('PRODUCTS');
  
  // get products and jobs
  var products = productSheet.getRange("A2:D" + productSheet.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var jobsRange = jobSheet.getRange("O2:BO" + jobSheet.getLastRow())
  var jobs = jobsRange.getValues()

  // get the list of products on the Jobs sheet and Product Codes on the products sheet
  var jobProducts = jobs.map(function(e){return e[1] })
  var prodCodes = products.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  // find the indices of every Job in the Product array
  var indices = jobProducts.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        prodCodes.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, i), new Map)
    );

  var priceArray = []

  // for each job get the Products index and the Price and push the price onto an array
  
jobs.forEach((j,i) =>{
    // assign value depending whether currency = Sterling or Euro
    if (jobs[i][0] === "STERLING" && jobs[i][1] !=""){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][2] 
    }
    else if (jobs[i][0] === "EURO" && jobs[i][1] !=""){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][3]  
   }
   var zoneSurcharge = j[49];
    priceArray.push([productValue + zoneSurcharge])
  })
  jobsRange.offset(0, 11,jobs.length,1).setValues(priceArray) 
  console.log(priceArray);
  var jobProducts = jobs.map(function(e){return e[12] })
  var prodCodes = products.map(function(e){return e[0]})
   // find the indices of every Job in the Product array
  var indices = jobProducts.map(
        Map.prototype.get,
        prodCodes.reduce((m, v, i) => m.set(v, i), new Map)
    );
   var priceArray = []
   // for each job get the Products index and the Price and push the price onto an array
jobs.forEach((j,i) =>{
    // assign value depending whether currency = Sterling or Euro
    if (jobs[i][0] === "STERLING" && jobs[i][12] !=""){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][2] 
    }
    else if (jobs[i][0] === "EURO" && jobs[i][12] !==""){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][3]  
   }
   var zoneSurcharge = j[49];
   
    priceArray.push([productValue + zoneSurcharge])
  })
  
  jobsRange.offset(0, 14,jobs.length,1).setValues(priceArray)
  
  SpreadsheetApp.flush
  
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike in column P rows 3 & 4 these cell are blank as there is no product code, when the script runs this gives "undefined" in rows 3 & 4 in column Z. Instead of the   output in the cell showing "undefined", the cells  rows 3 & 4 in column Z need to be empty. The same in row 2 column AC.  In the shared sheet I have included a sheet named required output. I hope you can understand. Thanks

Comment: The script should bring the price from this spreadsheet [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pt7YnN9fmoD4PE0o9oVPezK8Qz6ZmabyJbWXfdzFeMU/edit?usp=sharing] by matching the product codes from either columns P,AA,AD,AG,AJ,AM and the currency either EURO or STERLING from column O. Inserting the price in either columns Z,AC,AF,AI,AL,AO,AR for each product code in sheet [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dk57-ulWiHD_fYbEnYcMkqwQyDKkEyQVPNetqMVIgN0/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: @Tanaike I found the problem that was causing the undefined error result.  ```var zoneSurcharge = j[49];
    priceArray.push([productValue + zoneSurcharge])``` it runs correct when the var zoneSurcharge is removed with ```priceArray.push([productValue])``` Thank you anyway for your interest in trying to fix

Answer (score 1):

This script runs correct

````
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][2] + jobs[i][49]
    }
    else if (jobs[i][0] === "EURO" && jobs[i][12] !==""){
      var productValue = products[indices[i]][3]  + jobs[i][49]
   }
   
   
    priceArray.push([productValue])
  })
  })```
````